# ..., deshalb wird/werden 50% der Energie lokal erzeugt

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-usage

Wie soll es heissen:

- ..., deshalb wird 50% der Energie lokal erzeugt.
- ..., deshalb werden 50% der Energie lokal erzeugt.

Würde das Gefühl etwas anderes sagen, wenn es so wäre:

- ..., weshalb 50% der Energie lokal erzeugt wird.
- ..., weshalb 50% der Energie lokal erzeugt werden.

Grammatikalisch sind natürlich beide obigen Beispiele exakt gleich, ...

Comment: Es wäre besser, die Frage allgemeiner zu formulieren, damit sie später von Leuten, die im Grunde die gleiche Frage haben, wahrscheinlicher gefunden wird. Ein besserer Titel (und Fragestellung) hätte sein können: `Sind Pronzentangaben Plural oder Singular?`

Answer (score 4):

Energie ist nicht abzählbar, Prozente aber schon. Daher sind beide Formulierungen möglich, wobei nach meinem Sprachgefühl die "wird"-Variante passender ist.
Je nach Kontext könnte aber auch die "werden"-Formulierung die elegantere sein.

Answer (score 2):

Viele Menschen verstehen die Bedeutung von "Prozent" nicht richtig und sind deshalb verwirrt, ob "50%" Einzahl oder Mehrzahl ist.

"Prozent" ist Lateinisch für "von Hundert". Deshalb sind beispielsweise auch die Abkürzungen "%", "p.c." und "v.H." gleichbedeutend.

Versteht man "Prozent" einmal richtig, dann ist sofort klar, dass es "50% ***werden***" heißen muss:

> <s>Fünfzig der Abgeordneten wird mit "Ja" stimmen.</s>
>
> Fünfzig der Abgeordneten werden mit "Ja" stimmen.
>
> <s>Fünfzig von Hundert der Abgeordneten wird mit "Ja" stimmen.</s>
>
> Fünfzig von Hundert der Abgeordneten werden mit "Ja" stimmen.
>
> <s>50% der Abgeordneten wird mit "Ja" stimmen.</s>
>
> 50% der Abgeordneten werden mit "Ja" stimmen.